# XMPP Android - Can't create MultiUserChat

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I'm using asmack lastest version (now). And I can't create a MultiUserChat on Android.

This is what I get in the log:

> E/AndroidRuntime(  558): java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension E/AndroidRuntime(
>   558):        at
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.getMUCUserExtension(MultiUserChat.java:2000)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  558):        at
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.create(MultiUserChat.java:364)
>   ....

Who can help me solve this bug? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, did you actually go look at the asmack source and see what got incorrectly cast?

Answer (score 2):

use `muc.join();` directly insted of first using `muc.create`

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend, at least a [quick search on the jive community forums.](http://community.igniterealtime.org/community/developers/search.jspa?peopleEnabled=true&userID=&containerType=&container=&spotlight=true&q=ClassCast)

I think that you have [forgotten to register the Providers for XMPP Extensions.](http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/167897#167897) This gets normally done by smack via a config file, but this process is not possible on Android with asmack, so you need to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to create a MultiUserChat using smack, maybe you would come across some error!
I suggested you to use asmack instead of smack on Android!
you can get the asmack from github,https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack！
you must make sure that you have red the README.md before you use it!
when you want to call the api in every activity!you should call
`SmackAndroid.init(context)` firstly!
good luck!

besides that you much make sure that your room's name do not contain blank,when you want to create a multiuserchat or you maybe get odd errors!